# How to check the value of a button and create a condition in body mail based on the input checked with phpmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I created a carousel form. Only one question per slide. On the first slide is two radio buttons. With js, if I click on a button, I have two slides. If I click on the other button, I have 10 slides. then I want to send the form via phpmailer by making a condition in the body mail. But it doesn't work. 
See my code below.

Anyone could help me?

Thank you.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$v1 = $_POST['v1'];
$v2 = $_POST['v2'];
// .....
$msg = '';
  if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)){ 
  require './vendor/autoload.php';

// Create a message
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Host = 'ssl0.ovh.net';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setFrom('mail@example.com',$auditeur);
$mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com', 'Nico');
$mail->Subject = 'My form';
//Attach multiple files one by one
  for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
      // destination
      $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
      // fichier à uploader
      $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
      if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct])){
        // move_uploaded_file déplàce un fichier télécharger vers une destination
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($uploadfile, "my-attach" . $ct);
        } 
        else {
            $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }
      }
  }

  if($v1 == 'value1'){
  $mail->Body = '<p> This is the mail 1</p>'
  } else {
    echo "sd";
    $mail->Body .='<p>This is the mail 2</p>'; 
  }

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        $msg .= "Thank you ";
    }

  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <!-- SOME CODE -->
      </head>
      <body>
      <!-- SliDES CAROUSEL -->
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input href="#" data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="1" type="radio" 
      class="custom-control-input" id="radio1" name="v1" value="value1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio1">DATA FOR MAIL 1</label>
      </div>

      <!-- Default inline 2-->
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input href="#" data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="1" type="radio" 
       class="custom-control-input" id="radio2" name="v1" value="value2">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="radio2">DATA FOR MAIL 2</label>
      </div>

      <!-- IF I CLICK ON RADIO 1 I HAVE 2 SLIDES AFTER CONTROLLED WITH JS -->
      <!-- IF I CLICK ON RADIO 2 I HAVE 10 SLIDES AFTER CONTROLLED WITH JS -->


  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the input has the same name and a different value.
You can then determine which button was clicked by checking for the value.

```
<?php
echo $_POST['example']; // (Either btn 1 or btn 2 depending on what you picked)

<input type="radio" name="example" value="btn1"> Test 1
<input type="radio" name="example" value="btn2"> Test 2
```

Comment: You can get rid of the v2 variable now.
You are using `$mail->body .=` and a `$mail->body =`. Try solving that and then see what happens.

Comment: Yes i use ````$mail->Body = ```` and ````$mail->Body .=````. This is for my condition. If i click on radio button 1 send me a mail. If i click on radio button 2, send me an different mail.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have two submit in one form. So, I have to put a different value on each submit button. Then, I have to make condition on the submit buttons and not on the radio one.

`````
        if($_POST['submit'] == 'mail1'{
        //send mail 1
        else {
        send mail 2
        }````
`````